# Generating duplicate files in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a project in eclipse . All the files including jars, java files etc are getting doubled with 0 as suffix. I am not able to figure out what just went wrong in my project.

Comment: did u try cleaning the project or changing the workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the same problem. This is how I fixed it:

```
1. Right click on the `Project Name`
2. Select Build Path -> Configure Build Path
3. In Java Build Path, go to the tab Order and Export
4. Unchecked your .jar library
5. Clean your project before running.
```

Hope this would help resolving your trouble too... :)